# Copy or Add specific sheet from closed workbook, based on Cell value, to active workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have raw CSV data for each EU country, that I run a macro on to format it, make a pivot, etc. The Excel files all start with the country code, i.e.: AT report 201901, FR Report 201901, etc.

I have another Excel workbook, saved on a network drive, called VATCONTROLS, with sheets per country, so AT,FR,BE,DE etc.

I'm looking for a macro that will look at the first two digits of the activeworkbooks name, and then copy/paste the corresponding sheet from the closed VATControls workbook and add it to the active workbook.

How would I go about this? This is just part of the code. Newsheet is worksheet for another part of the code.

```vb
Dim excel As excel.Application
Dim wsGET As String
Dim wb As excel.Workbook
Dim sht As excel.Worksheet      

NewSheet.Activate
Range("A1").Activate
Range("A1") = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],2)"

wsGET = ActiveSheet.Range("b1")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\extosldva\documents\vatcontrols.xlsx")
Set sht = wsGET

 sht.Activate
 sht.Range("A1:A3").Copy
 sht.Range("B1:B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Sheet.Name = wsGET Then
Sheet.Activate
End If
Next

If Not targetSheetFound Then
Set Sheet = Sheets.Add
Sheet.Name = targetSheetName
End If
```

I have tried a lot of things, and combined a few sample code snippets from various sources with various results. The code is a mess and needs to be cleaned up, as it is not consistent, but I'd like this part to work, and I'm afraid I am mixing up several methods to achieve one goal.

To clarify: I want to copy or add an entire sheet from a closed workbook, where the name of the sheet matches the value in cell b1, on a new sheet in the active workbook. The part of the code after `{Set sht = wb.wsGET}` was just to see if that part works.

Answer (score 0):

@Dennis the following macro add a new sheet to Z.active workbook and copy country vat sheet from vatcontrol woorkbook

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim excel As excel.Application
Dim wsGET As String
Dim wb As excel.Workbook
Dim sht As excel.Worksheet
Dim ActvWB As String
Dim targetSheetFound As String

ActvWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Range("A1").Activate
Range("A1") = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],2)"

wsGET = ActiveSheet.Range("B1")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\extosldva\documents\vatcontrols.xlsx")
targetSheetFound = "Not Found"
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Sheet.Name = wsGET Then
targetSheetFound = "Found"
Sheets(wsGET).Copy After:=Workbooks(ActvWB).Sheets(Workbooks(ActvWB).Sheets.Count)
wb.Close
Exit For
End If
Next

Workbooks(ActvWB).Activate
If targetSheetFound = "Not Found" Then
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheet.Name = wsGET
End If
Worksheets(wsGET).Activate

MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```